# Dynamic Input via Repeater Get Data on Button Click

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, modelattribute, jquery.repeater

I am considering using [jquery.repeater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) in my Spring MVC project, but I am wondering how I would add the user's input to the model (I'm using @ModelAttribute for other, static fields). The repeater would basically consist of 4 different text inputs that I would need to read into an object so I end with a list/array of that type of object with as many as the user added using the repeater. If there's anything better than jquery.repeater that would make this easier to implement I'm open to that too.